# how to access data from axios in quasar

Tags: json, axios, quasar-framework

I need to access my data from mysql in quasar. i am trying to access it using axios but i dont understand data parsing. I can access some data when there is this format :  `{ "id": 1, "consommation": "125", "production": "345", "injection": "482", "soutirage": "128"}`

but i've got this format `[ { "id": 1, "consommation": "125", "production": "345", "injection": "482", "soutirage": "128", "datetime": null } ]`

and i can't access it with `axios.get ('http://localhost:3000/data').then(response => (this.info = response.data))`

i would to get my data like `axios.get ('http://localhost:3000/data').then(response => (this.info = response.data.id))`

thanks for any help,
have a goo day

Answer (score 0):

The format you got is valid, it means your data is in an array, so you can access it like a regular array. If you are sure that you have only one object in your array, you can use

```js
response.data[0].id
```

Comment: oh yes its working to get 1 object but if i have got many lines ?
Like this :
`[ { "id": 1, "consommation": "125", "production": "345", "injection": "482", "soutirage": "128", "datetime": null }, { "id": 2, "consommation": "152", "production": "845", "injection": "442", "soutirage": "471", "datetime": null } ]

`

Comment: It's an array, so you can store this array on `this.info` and iterate on it thanks to a loop later. It depends on how you use your data afterwards

Comment: I tried to print all values like this but it didnt work. I do this : 

`for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        axios.get ('http://localhost:3000/data').then(response => ( this.cons = response.data[i].consommation, this.prod = response.data[i].production))
      } 
`